# dropdown_search-0.4.6 is giving error in Flutter. Error is given below

Tags: android-studio, flutter

```
Running Gradle task 'assembly debug'...
/D:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dropdown_search-0.4.6/lib/dropdown_search.dart:116:9: Error: Type 'AutovalidateMode' not found.
  final AutovalidateMode autoValidateMode;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/D:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dropdown_search-0.4.6/lib/dropdown_search.dart:116:9: Error: 'AutovalidateMode' isn't a type.
  final AutovalidateMode autoValidateMode;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/D:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dropdown_search-0.4.6/lib/dropdown_search.dart:149:29: Error: Getter not found: 'AutovalidateMode'.
    this.autoValidateMode = AutovalidateMode.disabled,
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/D:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dropdown_search-0.4.6/lib/dropdown_search.dart:248:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'autovalidateMode'.
      autovalidateMode: widget.autoValidateMode,
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/form.dart:282:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const FormField({
        ^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- Where:
  Script 'D:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 896
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'D:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 26s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 2):

What is yours flutter version?

I had a similar problem and fixed upgrading flutter to 1.22.5.

**Try:**

```
flutter upgrade
```

**Font:** [github issue](https://github.com/danvick/flutter_form_builder/issues/484)